# SVG Gradient using Infinity in coordinates

Tags: canvas, svg, gradient

I stepped into this in an SVG file:

```
<linearGradient id="linearGradient6019" xlink:href="#linearGradient6001" y1="-Infinity" y2="Infinity" x1="0.401576" x2="0.39193"/>
```

And i went to check on the specs:

```
https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#LinearGradientElementX1Attribute
```

And i saw that the spec gives a

```
 spreadMethod = "pad | reflect | repeat"
```

I think that spreadMethod = "pad" should behave like infinity on coordinates.

Anyone stepped in this before and has some suggestion how to handle this infinity when parsing a gradient ?

I need to translate those infinity in numbers to print it on canvas with

```
ctx.createLinearGradient(x,y,z,q);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinity is not allowed as a value so the input file is invalid.

Given that, the linearGradient will use its default or lacuna values for x1 and x2 which are 0% and 100% respectively.

Comment: ok so those are just bad made svg from some application. i can parse them with 0 and 100 value.